# Center Align Table - wkhtmlpdf

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

Trying to convert a HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf.

I want the table in the generated PDF to be at the center but the table represented here in HTML always aligns left in the created PDF?

What could be going wrong?

PS: I am new to the front-end altogether. I think i am making some small mistake in styling.

```
<div class="divGeneral" id="sumDiv">
            <table id="infoTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Pr Name:&nbsp</th>
                    <td><textarea id="pName" class="noBorderInput" rows="1"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Su Date:&nbsp</th>
                    <td><textarea id="suDate" class="noBorderInput" rows="1"></textarea></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </div>
```

The style sheet has

```
.divGeneral {
    width: 100%;
    //float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#sumDiv {
    // margin-bottom: 50px;
   // display: inline-block;
    // float: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#infoTable th {
    border: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px 2px 0px 2px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#infoTable td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 3px 2px 3px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
textarea
{
    margin: 0px;
}
textarea .multiline{
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can add

```
#infoTable{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This simply **center-align the table in `.divGeneral`** which is `width:100%`.

I also removed some css code that has no effect in the current task.

**Please run the code below to see if this is what you want.**

```css
.divGeneral {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#sumDiv {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#infoTable{
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#infoTable th {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px 2px 0px 2px;
    text-align: right;
}

#infoTable td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 3px 2px 3px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

textarea .multiline{
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divGeneral" id="sumDiv">
  <table id="infoTable">
     <tr>
       <th>Pr Name:&nbsp</th>
       <td><textarea id="pName" class="noBorderInput" rows="1"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th>Su Date:&nbsp</th>
       <td><textarea id="suDate" class="noBorderInput" rows="1"></textarea></td>
     </tr> 
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didnt serve my purpose as i think the problem is with wkhtml library and table alignment. But i think your approach is in general correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox method.I hope this will work for you.

```
.divGeneral {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```